# Как работать с Promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Допустим, что я хочу вывести какой-то блок на странице:

```
$('.some-element').append(`
Привет, ${data.user_name}. Вы успешно зарегистрировались в системе. Ваш город определён, как ${getCityByCode(data.code)}`
);
```

Но дело в том, что в функции `getTimeByCode()` используется асинхронный ajax-запрос, например:

```
function getCityByCode(param) {
    $.getJSON('/json/cities.json', function(json){
        for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
            if(json[i].code == param)
                return json[i].cityname;
    })
}
```

А следственно, функция `append()` не будет ждать, пока выполнится функция `getCityByCode()`. Для этого нежно использовать Promise. Но как это правильно сделать? Как заставить `append()` дожидаться выполнения функции?

Comment: а почему аппенд не всунуть вместо ретурна скажем ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych а если у меня 5-6 таких асинхронных функций будет?

Comment: ну 5-6 раз вызвать ajax запрос, каждый раз передавая ему колбэк функцию на саксес, а с промисами будет 5-6 промисов, в которые будут передаваться колбэк функции, я это все вижу именно так

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych не 5-6 одинаковых вызовов, а 5-6 вызовов разных функций, в которых должны быть промисы.

Comment: никто и не говорил об одинаковых, 5-6 аяксов или 5-6 промисов, особой разницы не вижу

Comment: Тогда у меня будет 5-6 вложенных циклов в теле 5-6 асинхронных вызовов? не ужас ли?

Comment: если функция с циклом одна и та же, то можно ее вынести в отдельную

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, `append` не будет ждать запроса, более того в вашей конструкции не получится вернуть `cityname` напрямую, как результат работы функции `getCityByCode`.

В данном случае можно использовать Promise, необходимо, чтобы функция `getCityByCode` возвращала объект Promise, в который нужно передавать асинхронную функцию, которая по завершении действия должна вызвать один из аргументов `resolve` или `reject`.

Должно получиться как-то так:

```
function getCityByCode(param) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.getJSON('/json/cities.json', function(json) {
            for (let city of json) {
                if (city.code == param) {
                    resolve(city.cityname);
                }
            }
        })
    });
}

getCityByCode(data.code)
    .then(function(cityName) {
        $('.some-element').append(cityName);
    });
```